# Unable to use LAG function mysql

Tags: sql, mariadb

I understood with the new version of mysql 8 lead/lag functions would work (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)

Here is my version
mysqladmin  Ver 9.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Server version          10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1
Protocol version        10
Connection              Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket             /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 32 min 17 sec

I'm using mysql workbench to connect

When I run a simple lead example it doesn't show as a function only KEYW and throws the following error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

```
    select a, lag(a,1) over (order_by f_date)
    from table1;
```

Comment: Please show us the statement that generates the error

Comment: Simple statement added but it's not the syntax the function doesn't seem to be available for some reason despite being added according to the notes for version 8

Answer (score 4):

You are running MariaDB, not MySQL, and the LAG function was only introduced in MariaDB 10.2. You are running MariaDB 10.1, so need to upgrade to a later version. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/lag/